# Is there an equivalent to new Gson().toJson(Object) in FasterXML/Jackson Java library?

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson, fasterxml

My question is really basic: is there an equivalent to [new Gson().toJson(Object)](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#toJson(java.lang.Object)) in [FasterXML/Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core) Java library?

And if yes which one has the better performance?

Thanks

Comment: In Jackson `new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(Object)`

Answer (score 1):

As @Zutty suggested:

> In Jackson new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(Object)

I tried it but I get a **com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException**

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Direct self-reference leading to cycle (through reference chain: com.learnkeeper.shared.entities.RootBook["permissionRef"]->com.googlecode.objectify.impl.ref.LiveRef["key"]->com.googlecode.objectify.Key["root"])
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter._handleSelfReference(BeanPropertyWriter.java:781)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:569)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:666)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:156)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:575)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:666)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:156)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:575)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:666)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:156)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:129)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._configAndWriteValue(ObjectMapper.java:3385)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(ObjectMapper.java:2779)
```

While with **new Gson().toJson(Object)** I get a nice **Json**:

```
{"id":4512395720392704,"origin":"FRENCH","target":"ENGLISH","wordKeys":[],"name":"Test","creation":"Aug 11, 2015 8:43:02 PM","modification":"Aug 11, 2015 8:43:02 PM","permissionRef":{"key":{"raw":{"kind":"Permission","id":6737807255011328}}},"lastVersion":true}
```

Additional info: all my **Java Object** that I would like to log implement **java.io.Serializable**

Comment: Jackson doesn't manage back-references automagically. There is a circular reference chain somewhere in the object graph you are trying to serialize, so Jackson gets stuck in an infinite loop. I'm guessing a bi-directional parent <--> child relationship. See this for the solution... http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureBiDirReferences

Answer (score 1):

The folks at takipi did a performance [comparison](http://blog.takipi.com/the-ultimate-json-library-json-simple-vs-gson-vs-jackson-vs-json/) of several json parsers, including both gson and jackson. It turns out that it depends on the types of documents being parsed. Gson is faster with smaller documents and jackson is faster with large documents. A 3rd alternative, json.simple, provides more consistent performance across both large and small documents.

Answer (score 0):

Couple more differences to add:

- Gson uses field values to populate the JSON string, where as Jackson uses getter values.
- By default Jackson uses public Getter visibility to access the value. But we can configure it with the following:

> objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.GETTER,
> Visibility.PROTECTED_AND_PUBLIC);

See the example:

```
 public class ParentObj {
    private UUID id;    
    public ParentObj(UUID id) {
        this.id = id;       
    }   
    public UUID getUUID() {
        return id;
    }       
}
 Main.java
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    System.out.println("ObjectMapper out > " + objectMapper.writeValueAsString(parentObj));

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    System.out.println("Gson out > " + gson.toJson(parentObj));
```

output:

```
ObjectMapper out > {"uuid":"5d49e053-7954-4681-a3cc-1b5101d9712c"}
Gson out > {"id":"5d49e053-7954-4681-a3cc-1b5101d9712c"}
```